# trying to update data in databse using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-4

I  am trying to update data in the database using angular in Laravel 4 but the data is'nt get inserted, and a blank value is getting stored in to the database. Please find the bug and try to insert the passed value insteed of blank value.

> JS File

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.updateFunction = function(updateId) {
    $http.get("http://localhost/crud/public/registration_update_page/" + updateId).then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log('successCallback');
      console.log(response);
      alert("Row with id " + updateId + ", updated..!");
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log('errorCallback');
      console.log(response);
    });
  };
});
```

> .PHP File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h2>Registration</h2><br/>
<table border=1>
<tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" ng-model="nam" name="nam"><br/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="email" ng-model="email" name="email"><br/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" ng-model="password" name="password"><br/></td></tr>
<tr><td>City:</td><td><input type="text" ng-model="city" name="city"><br/></td></tr>
<tr><td><button ng-click="insertFunc()" type="submit">Submit</button></td></tr>
</table>

</div>
</form>

<table style="width:100%" border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Password</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Update</th>
    <th>Delete</th>

  </tr>

  <tr ng-init='show = true' ng-repeat="x in query" ng-hide='!show'></div>
    <!-- ng-hide will work when it is true in condition -->
    <td>{{x.id}}</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="{{x.name}}" name="edited_name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="{{x.email}}" name="edited_email"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="{{x.password}}" name="edited_password"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="{{x.city}}" name="edited_city"></td><br/>
    <td><input type="submit" ng-click="updateFunction(x.id);" value="Update"></td>
    <td><button ng-click="deleteFunction(x.id);show = false">Delete</button></td>

    <!-- !show==false means !false i.e., true -->
  </tr><div>
</body>
</html>
```

> Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Session;
use Redirect;

class NewController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
public function registration_update_function(Request $request)
    {
      $updateId = $request->id;
      $edited_name = $request->edited_name;
      $edited_city = $request->edited_city;
      $users1 = DB::table('angular_registration')->where('id', '=', $updateId)->update(['city' => $edited_city]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you see the response on ajax call in inspect ?

Comment: No, only Id is displaying there as "Object {data: " 71", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}"

Comment: And you need to pass the name and city as well, right ?

Comment: Thanx mohit for your effort

Comment: Same thing I done with POST method what you've done with GET method in AngularJS.
Post method is preferable to use.

Comment: Could you please post your running code with POST method ?

Comment: I have already posted an example, right now I am not having laravel 4 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem myself
This works for ANGULAR.JS with Laravel 4 to run insert,update,delete and select queries of the MySql DataBase.

> VIEW

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h2>Registration</h2><br/>
<table border=1>
<tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" ng-model="nam" name="nam"><br/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="email" ng-model="email" name="email"><br/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" ng-model="password" name="password"><br/></td></tr>
<tr><td>City:</td><td><input type="text" ng-model="city" name="city"><br/></td></tr>
<tr><td><button ng-click="insertFunc()" type="submit">Submit</button></td></tr>
</table>

</div>
</form>

<table style="width:100%" border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Password</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Update</th>
    <th>Delete</th>

  </tr>

  <tr ng-init='show = true' ng-repeat="x in query" ng-hide='!show'></div>
    <!-- ng-hide will work when it is true in condition -->
    <td>{{x.id}}</td>
    <td>{{x.name}}<input type="text" ng-model="edited_name"></td>
    <td>{{x.email}}<input type="text" ng-model="edited_email"></td>
    <td>{{x.password}}<input type="text" ng-model="edited_password"></td>
    <td>{{x.city}}<input type="text" ng-model="edited_city"></td><br/>
    <td><input type="submit" ng-click="updateFunction(x.id,edited_name,edited_email,edited_password,edited_city);" value="Update"></td>
    <td><button ng-click="deleteFunction(x.id);show = false">Delete</button></td>

    <!-- !show==false means !false i.e., true -->
  </tr><div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

   $scope.deleteFunction = function(deleteId)
          {
            $http.get("http://localhost/crud/public/registration_delete_page/"+deleteId)
            .then(function successCallback(response)
            {
              console.log('successCallback');
              console.log(response);
              alert("Row with id "+deleteId+", deleted..!");
            },
            function errorCallback(response)
            {
              console.log('errorCallback');
              console.log(response);
            });
          };
    $scope.updateFunction = function(updateId,edited_name,edited_email,edited_password,edited_city)
          {
            $http.get("http://localhost/crud/public/registration_update_page/"+updateId+"/"+edited_name+"/"+edited_email+"/"+edited_password+"/"+edited_city)
            .then(function successCallback(response)
            {
              //$scope.edited_name = edited_name;
              console.log('successCallback');
              console.log(response);
              alert("Row with id "+updateId+", updated..!");
            },
            function errorCallback(response)
            {
              console.log('errorCallback');
              console.log(response);
            });

          };

    $scope.insertFunc = function() {
        $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : 'http://localhost/crud/public/registration_data_page',
          data    : {nam:$scope.nam,email:$scope.email,password:$scope.password,city:$scope.city}
         }).then(function successCallback(response) {
          console.log('successCallback');
          console.log(response);

  }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log('errorCallback');
          console.log(response);
  });

}

$http({method:'GET', url:'http://localhost/crud/public/registration_json_page'}).success(function(response){
$scope.query = response;
});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

> Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Session;
use Redirect;

class NewController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
public function registration_data_function(Request $request)
    {
      echo $nam_value = $request->nam;
      echo $email_value = $request->email;
      echo $password_value = $request->password;
      echo $city_value = $request->city;

      $reg = DB::table('angular_registration')->insert(['name' => $nam_value, 'email' => $email_value, 'password'=>$password_value, 'city'=>$city_value]);
    }

    public function registration_json_function(Request $request)
    {
      $query = DB::select('select * from angular_registration');
      return response($query);
    }

    public function registration_function(Request $request)
    {
      $query = DB::select('select * from angular_registration');
      return view('registration');
    }

    public function registration_delete_function(Request $request)
    {
      $deleteId = $request->id;
      return $users = DB::table('angular_registration')->where('id', '=', $deleteId)->delete(); 
    }

    public function registration_update_function(Request $request)
    {
      echo $updateId = $request->id;
      echo $edited_name = $request->edited_name;
      echo $edited_email = $request->edited_email;
      echo $edited_password = $request->edited_password;
      echo $edited_city = $request->edited_city;

      $users1 = DB::table('angular_registration')->where('id', '=', $updateId)->update(['name' => $edited_name,'email' => $edited_email,'password' => $edited_password,'city' => $edited_city]);
    }
}
```

> ROUTE

```
<?php

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
    | It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
    | and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
    |
    */

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::auth();

Route::get('/registration', 'NewController@registration_function');

Route::post('/registration_data_page', 'NewController@registration_data_function');

Route::get('/registration_json_page', 'NewController@registration_json_function');

Route::get('registration_delete_page/{id}', 'NewController@registration_delete_function');

Route::get('registration_update_page/{id}/{edited_name}/{edited_email}/{edited_password}/{edited_city}', 'NewController@registration_update_function');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with post method and following code and pass full x object / scope and x.id in this function updateFunction(x, x.id);

**Angular Code**

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://localhost/crud/public/registration_update_page/',
 data: { x: x, id = x.id }
}

$http(req).then(function(){
   //Success
}, function(){

});
```

**On server side PHP**

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: url: 'http://localhost/crud/public/registration_update_page/' this would also need the ID parameter to go to the controller page in laravel 4 as:"url: 'http://localhost/crud/public/registration_update_page/updateId'"

Comment: Please try to run in laravel, and then answer. It would be helpful only then.

Comment: In PHP it will work in this way, in whatever framework you do. Or provide me jsfiddle so I can check your problem.

Comment: if I am using this "<td><input type="text" value="{{x.name}}" ng-model="edited_name"></td>" instead of "<td>{{x.name}}<input type="text"  ng-model="edited_name"></td>", the value of "x.name" is not dispalying. wht to do ?

Comment: Just remove value attribute from input

Comment: sorry but we have to to like this: "<td><input type="text" ng-value="x.name" ng-model="edited_name"></td>"

Comment: Now I need to make this field editable only when a click happens. Currently it is editable without happening any click.

Comment: Make span to show that value and when click happens you can hide span and show the input box by using ng-show and ng-hide.

Comment: If my answer helps you in any way just marked it or do upvote